# Redux form sends outdated data on second submit

Tags: reactjs, react-forms

I have a page with multiple dropdowns and each dropdown sends different data to server.

```js
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submitMember)}>
  <DropDown />
  <button type="submit">Apply changes</button>
  <DropDown />
  <button type="submit">Apply changes</button>
</form>


const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
  member: getFormValues(`${ownProps.form}`)(state)
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(reduxForm({ enableReinitialize: true })(MemberRow))
```

When I submit first time everything works correctly. But when I submit second time form sends outdated data from first submit.
I checked redux storage and data here is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `keepDirtyOnReinitialize: true` solved the issue.

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(reduxForm({ enableReinitialize: true, keepDirtyOnReinitialize: true })(MemberRow))
```

From [docs](https://redux-form.com/6.0.2/docs/api/reduxform.md/#-keepdirtyonreinitialize-boolean-optional-):

> keepDirtyOnReinitialize : boolean [optional]
>
> When set to true and enableReinitialize is also set, the form will
> retain the value of dirty fields when reinitializing. When this option
> is not set (the default), reinitializing the form replaces all field
> values. This option is useful in situations where the form has live
> updates or continues to be editable after form submission; it prevents
> reinitialization from overwriting user changes. Defaults to false.